# why does hasError return false even when the error exists for the formarray?

Tags: angular, forms

```
this.emailForm = this.fb.group({
   emails: this.fb.array([], [this.validateArrayNotEmpty]),
});


this.emailForm.controls['emails'].setErrors({'incorrectEmail': true});
console.log(this.emailForm.get('emails'));
console.log(this.emailForm.get('emails').hasError('incorrectEmail'));





 validateArrayNotEmpty(c: FormControl) {
    if (c.value && c.value.length === 0) {
      return {
        validateArrayNotEmpty: { valid: false }
      };
    }
    return null;
  }
```

As you can see in the photo below, there is a value called incorrectEmail in the error object.
But still, the hasError method returns false.

[image]

Comment: can you show `emailForm` initialization code ?

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID I added the init code.

Comment: what does this method `validateArrayNotEmpty` ? ( because without it your code is working as supposed)

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID I added the code for validateArrayNotEmpty too.

Comment: i tried your code and it's logging `true` , which version of Angular are you working with ? do you make any other actions on your `formArray` ?

Comment: @MohamedAliRACHID angular core 9.1 and I do not.